# HTML script tag function not reading in in-line onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that is supposed to switch a theme by using a `<select>` tag and the `onchange` attribute. It says a function I defined was never defined. Please help.

```js
var themer = document.getElementById('themer');
var body = document.getElementById('body');

document.getElementById('themer').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('dark', 'light');
  document.getElementById('body').classList.add(document.getElementById('themer').value);
});

function change(theme) {
  document.getElementById('body').classList.remove('dark', 'light');
  document.getElementById('body').classList.add(theme);
};
```

```css
.dark {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="light">
  <select id="themer" class="light" onchange="change(this.value);">
    <option value="light">light</option>
    <option value="dark">dark</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: What if you put the `<script>` section right befote `</body>`?

Comment: Where is your js code defined? If it is in some function (like a ready/onload callback) it wont be defined in global space which is what js event attributes use to locate functions

Comment: thx, I haven't used in-line js in forever

Comment: I think the edition of @Quentin was not a good ideia.. because its remove the main problem of the question...

Comment: Also you don't have to keep reusing `document.getElementById('themer')` when you have it saved to a variable, just use the variable.

Comment: Rip, nvm, it still says `change is not defined`

Comment: Also, the var wasn't working

Comment: Your code should work. See the snippet you've provided...

Answer (score -1):

This line of code has a rouge bracket which is breaking your JS:

`document.getElementById('body').classList.adddocument.getElementById('themer').value);`

Should be

`document.getElementById('body').classList.add(document.getElementById('themer').value);`

see [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhgc926v/) of fix

Comment: It didn't work, it still says change is not defined.

Comment: See demo link above using inline without change error.